# How does this integration work?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation

In dealing with a question about equilibrium values for the heat equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac k r \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)$$

after a number of computations, we find that the condition for equilibrium implies

$$0=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int^b_ar\,u(r,t)\,\mathrm{d}r=\int^b_ar\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\,\mathrm{d}r=k\int^b_a\,\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)\mathrm{d}r$$

Which makes sense. However, the calculation then does:

$$\dots=b\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\big|_{r=b}-a\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\big|_{r=a}$$

How does this occur? Perhaps I'm rusty on my integration, but wouldn't both the partial derivative and $r$ in the integrand be evaluated? And by that, wouldn't integration by parts be used? It seems that $r$ wasn't even touched, since its integral is $\frac {r^2} 2$...

Basically, could someone walk me through how to perform the integration

$$\int^b_a\,\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)\mathrm{d}r$$

Comment: Can you do $\int_a^b f'(r)\;dr$ to start with?

Comment: That's just $f(b)-f(a)$, right?

Comment: Right.  Your question is an example of this.